Anthropomorphic rats living in an apocalyptic wasteland
Trying to gather information on a dark animated film that I saw several years ago.  It was much in the style of a Bakshi/Bluth film. It included several anthropomorphic rats who lived in some sort of apocalyptic wasteland. The main character had orange hair and a military jacket, and one of the villains was a bald rat with some sort of tattoo on his forehead. I believe there was a female rat who somehow got poisoned and kidnapped also. 
Very hazy on the details, I only watched a portion of it as it was playing in some monitors when I went to a local club to watch a band play. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

That sounds like Rock & Rule to me. Quite "gritty" for an animated film with an art style that would sit next to any disney film. There is a trailer on Youtube. 

Wow! This actually looks pretty awesome!
